# SSH into a shared text editor for phone screen code tests?

Tags: unix, ssh

Is there a simple way to have someone ssh into a machine and edit a text file while I view text they are writing?

I am interested in using this for phone screen interviews. Basically, I would tell the candidate to ssh into a particular machine and edit/compile a source file to test programming ability. Ideally, I would like to see what they are typing in real time rather than only when they save.

Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is *the* solution to this conundrum; see the `-x` option to create a shared session.  You can create the session beforehand and have the dialin [ :) ] account invoke `screen -x -R` to attach to it.  (I habitually use `screen -A -U -R -x`.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use GNU Screen's multiuser feature (also called session sharing). http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser

It might be easier to setup a VNC & watch them that way. TightVNC allows you to run a 'web' server that they can connect to via a browser. http://www.tightvnc.com/winst.php#start_java

Answer (score 0):

I've had a nothing but good experiences using a [Google Doc](http://docs.google.com) for this. Realtime updating and collaboration for both parties, realtime cursor positions and highlighting for both parties, and it's stored somewhere really easy to get to afterwards, with revision history.

No syntax highlighting or auto-formatting, however, but honestly it's fine without it.

Comment: I think the OP was looking for the candidate to be able to compile as well.